# Where can I find out where the react proptypes warning is coming from?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I recently bumped our react version to 15.6.2, which includes the React PropTypes deprecation warning. I ran the JSCodeshift codemod script in our project directory and it successfully modified hundreds of files. However, in our webpack for npm run build, I still get this: `Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in  React v16.0. Use the latest available v15.* prop-types package from npm instead. For info on usage, compatibility, migration and more....`. Where and how can I track down the file(s) that are causing this warning message to output? It is not showing up in the developer console, just in my terminal.

Comment: A naive project-wide search for `React.PropTypes` might just work?

Comment: Tried that with IntelliJ, no results. Which is why I'm confused I keep getting that warning, and would be helpful if I could find exactly which file is throwing it

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I assume this is from a dependency, but I'm at a loss to determine which one.